Pigment CSS wrapper
I am trying to create my wrapper function around styled function from @pigment-css/react.
I will not bother you about the details about my wrapper, so I will provide the simplest wrapper, just to demostrate.
So here's the code:
import { styled } from "@pigment-css/react"

function myStyled(tag: "div" | "p" | "span") {
  return styled(tag)
}

const Root = myStyled("div")({
  margin: "auto",
  maxWidth: "36rem",
})

So, when trying to render Root as a React component, I get the following error. This is a screenshot from Vite environment, but it also happens in Next.JS.


As Pigment CSS works as a static extractor, it's not able to act fully like runtime css-in-js library, so you should not wrap styled, but you could do this in another ways:
Option 1
import * as React from 'react';
import { styled } from '@pigment-css/react';
import type { ThemeArgs } from '@pigment-css/react/theme';

// Create shared styles dynamically
const getBaseStyles = ({ theme: { vars } }: ThemeArgs) => ({
    color: vars.palette.foreground,
    backgroundColor: vars.palette.background,
})

const Root = styled('div')(props => ({
    // Apply shared styles
    ...getBaseStyles(props),

    // Apply custom styles
    margin: "auto",
    maxWidth: "36rem",
}))

const Typography = styled('span')(props => ({
    // Apply shared styles
    ...getBaseStyles(props),

    // Apply custom styles
    fontWeight: 600,
}))

export default function PigmentCSSV1() {
    return (
        <>
            <Root as="div">Hello, div!</Root>
            <Root as="section">Hello, section!</Root>
            <Typography as="p">Hello, p!</Typography>
            <Typography as="span">Hello, span!</Typography>
        </>
    )
}

Option 2
Also, the Pigment CSS allows you to override tag/component on the render time by passing as="div" prop on the styled component, for example:
<Root as="div">Hello, div!</Root>
<Root as="section">Hello, section!</Root>
<Typography as="p">Hello, p!</Typography>
<Typography as="span">Hello, span!</Typography>

Will be rendered to:

So, you could do one single Styled Component and then customize it:
import * as React from 'react';
import { styled } from '@pigment-css/react';

// Create base styled component and pass base tag that will be overridden on render time
const BaseComponent = styled('div')(({ theme: { vars } }) => ({
    color: vars.palette.foreground,
    backgroundColor: vars.palette.background,
}))

const Root = styled(BaseComponent)(props => ({
    // Apply custom styles
    margin: "auto",
    maxWidth: "36rem",
}))

const Typography = styled(BaseComponent)(props => ({
    // Apply custom styles
    fontWeight: 600,
}))

export default function PigmentCSSV2() {
    return (
        <>
            <Root as="div">Hello, div!</Root>
            <Root as="section">Hello, section!</Root>
            <Typography as="p">Hello, p!</Typography>
            <Typography as="span">Hello, span!</Typography>
        </>
    )
}

Option 3
Pigment CSS has a great css function that might help you. With this function, you can create separate styles that you can then add to any component.
import * as React from 'react';
import { styled, css } from '@pigment-css/react';

// Create base styled component and pass base tag that will be overridden on render time
const baseStyleClass = css(({ theme: { vars } }) => ({
    color: vars.palette.foreground,
    backgroundColor: vars.palette.background,
}))

const Root = styled('div')(props => ({
    // Apply custom styles
    margin: "auto",
    maxWidth: "36rem",
}))

const Typography = styled('span')(props => ({
    // Apply custom styles
    fontWeight: 600,
}))

export default function PigmentCSSV3() {
    return (
        <>
            <Root as="div" className={baseStyleClass}>Hello, div!</Root>
            <Root as="section" className={baseStyleClass}>Hello, section!</Root>
            <Typography as="p" className={baseStyleClass}>Hello, p!</Typography>
            <Typography as="span" className={baseStyleClass}>Hello, span!</Typography>
        </>
    )
}

P.S.
If you need any resources about how PigmentCSS works or how you could do something, you can find working examples in Material UI (next, V6) - https://github.com/mui/material-ui/blob/393f744dfc49554321f3e296c1f104198f3c0a59/packages/mui-material/src/Button/Button.js#L72-L347
